# How to install Blender on OS X (Blender directories?)

Tags: customization, path, osx

I need help installing Blender on OS X. I unzipped the file, dragged the folder to the Applications folder, ran Blender, opened User Preferences, went to the directories setup (File tab), but there were no directories listed. I looked in the manual, which referenced a folder which is not on my system, or, if it is, I cannot find it. Then, I read that I have to create each directory, but I don’t know where to create them.

Comment: TL:DR; don't worry about those, you don't need them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install any directories. If you're looking for where the scripts, config and cache folders are, they're in the Application Support folder under your user account directory.

> - /Users/$USER/Library/Application
>     Support/Blender/2.74/cache
> - /Users/$USER/Library/Application
>     Support/Blender/2.74/config
> - /Users/$USER/Library/Application
>     Support/Blender/2.74/scripts

The cache folder is where the BVH cache files are saved, and you can sometimes free up quite a lot of space by deleting them.

The config folder is where your startup and userpref files are kept.

The scripts/addons folder is where all your installed addons will be.

There will be separate folder for each version of Blender under Application Support/Blender.

If you're looking for Scripts/Addons/Presets/Modules that come with the Blender install, you have to look inside the Blender.app file. On a Mac, the application appears as a single file, but it's actually a folder with files within it.

If you right click on the Blender.app file, and choose Show Package Contents, you'll see a Contents folder. Open that and you'll see a number of files and folders. The scripts and presets are in the Resources folder.

The file hierarchy is like this:

```
Blender 2.74.app
+--Contents
   +--Resources
      +--2.74
         +--datafiles
         +--python
         +--scripts
```

Answer (score 2):

Blender has specific places that it looks for addons and config files and stores temporary files, you don't need to configure these locations.

As described in [the manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/file.html) most of the File Paths that can be configured in the preferences are "**default search paths**" which means they are the folder that will be displayed in the file browser when you choose to open a file of that type. For example if you set Fonts to `desktop/MyFonts` then when you click "load a new font button" in a text object, the file browser will start in your `MyFonts` folder,

Blender will not create these folders for you and you can create them anywhere that is convenient for you or choose any existing folder for each one.